# count the number of pages in pdf file

Tags: python, pdf

I have a problem when I use  this code to count the number of pages in pdf file :

```
if j[i].rstrip() == "Page" or j[i].rstrip() == "page":
            rxcountpages = re.compile(r"/Type\s*/Page([^s]|$)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
            data = file("/home/suleiman/Desktop/CVE-2011-2462_36EE5F9C51316E060657AA86D48670E8","rb")

            print len(rxcountpages.findall(data))
```

the error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_scanner.py", line 89, in

```
main()
```

File "pdf_scanner.py", line 72, in main

```
print len(rxcountpages.findall(data))
```

TypeError: expected string or buffer

can an one help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to read the contents of the file:

```
data = open("/home/suleiman/Desktop/CVE-2011-2462_36EE5F9C51316E060657AA86D48670E8","rb").read()
```