# Using R, how can someone count the number of pages in a PDF file?

Tags: r, pdf, count

I have about a hundred long PDF files in a directory and would like to know whether R can count how many pages are in each file.  My operating system is Windows 8.

Here is the link to a 10-page PDF file, in case this helps you test your solution.  [MWE pdf file](https://www.pdf-tools.com/public/downloads/whitepapers/whitepaper-pdfprimer.pdf)

It appears to be possible to count PDF pages with python, but I don't know that language [python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597825/count-the-number-of-pages-in-pdf-file).  Other solutions have been discussed on SO using, e.g., Imagemagick. and C##.

Comment: If `Rpoppler::PDF_info(filename)$Pages
` doesn't work, then the (prbly) the quickest way is to grab [poppler for Windows](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/) and use `system2` to run `pdfinfo` on the files and extract the `Pages:` line.

Comment: Note that `Rpoppler` doesn't appear to be available for Windows.

Comment: I haven't tried to get it to compile on Windows (I had to use `type="source"` on OS X, too) but since Kurt made it I made the assumption that if all the stars are aligned on the Windows box it would work. Another option is to use the [standalone poppler tools for Windows](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/) and use `system2` to instrument `pdfinfo` and grab the `Pages:` line.

Comment: I hadn't tried to install it from source, since the DESCRIPTION file states 'OS_type: unix`.  But having just tried now, I get the error `ERROR: Unix-only package`.  And I apologize, my previous comment was unfairly short.  I had meant to share that restriction in the interest of saying installing the poppler tools for windows is probably the way to go.  I'll work on that to see if I can get a workable solution.

Comment: No worries, but I wouldn't spend too much time. Getting compiled things for R to work on Windows is a dark art. `poppler` has so many large-scale dependencies that the effort may not be fruitful. Much of this problem stems from the toolchain imposed by R. I'm not sure if the python folks have such constraints.

Comment: Is there anything default approach which works in Debian? I cannot get Poppler in R 3.3.2 of Debian 8.5. Here a new thread about the case http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331175/16920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On R version 3.3.2 `pdftools` works:

```
library(pdftools)
pdfInfo <- pdf_info(<path to PDF file>)
pdfInfo$pages
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a Windows 7 machine, but my experiences on Windows 8 make me think it should work just as well for you.

I wasn't able to compile the `Rpoppler` package, and as hrbrmstr points out, it's probably not worth fighting.  If you have 7-Zip, you can extract the poppler tools for Windows.  I've extracted them to the location `C:\poppler`.  Once there, I can do the following

```
file_name <- "C:/[file_path]/whitepaper-pdfprimer.pdf"

pdf_pages <- function(file_name){
  require(magrittr)
  pages <- system2("C:/poppler/bin/pdfinfo.exe",
                   args = file_name,
                   stdout = TRUE)
  pages[grepl("Pages:", pages)] %>%
    gsub("Pages:", "", .) %>%
    as.numeric()
}

pdf_pages(file_name)
```

And if you have a vector of file names you want to pass

```
vapply(file_names, pdf_pages, numeric(1))
```

Credit to @hrbrmstr for pointing out the poppler tools (I'd never heard of them until today).

Comment: Try the `Rpoppler` package? I believe it will work on Linux.

Comment: Yes, it works in Linux, confirmed. This works `Rpoppler::PDF_info("/usr/share/doc/cvs/cvs.pdf")$Pages`. Discussed here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331185/16920