# How to count the number of pages in a PDF from R?

Tags: r, pdf

Is there a way to count the number of pages in a PDF file from R? If not, is there another OS-independent way to do this? So far, the only answer I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235038/using-r-how-can-someone-count-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file), and it is specific to Windows 7.

I am trying to compile some reports in R and `knitr`, aggregating the PDF plot output from a previous script, which automatically processes hundreds of data sets. Some of the datasets are bad, and end up breaking the plot function. Since the plot function is wrapped in the `pdf` function, an empty PDF file gets produced, is found by the report, and breaks `pdflatex`. Trying to modify the analysis script to avoid producing these PDF's in the first place has proven to be difficult, and is very case-specific. I would really like to have some function which I can embed in the report that will check the PDF for >=1 page(s) before including it. I would prefer an R based solution, though a bash, LaTeX, `knitr`, or pdflatex solution might also suffice.

EDIT: Also, as is mentioned in the previous answer I linked to, I tried to use `Rpoppler` ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rpoppler/Rpoppler.pdf)) but cannot get it to compile. I am using R version 3.3.0 in a CentOS 6 environment without admin access.

Comment: check out the `pdftools` pkg

Comment: I am trying `pdftools` right now but so far I am unable to get it compiled in CentOS 6, and since this is a server I do not have admin rights to try installing with its system dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but you can make system level calls from R using `system`, so you could use pdfinfo (e.g., pdfinfo file.pdf | grep 'Pages'). jk. Centos doesn't seem to ship with pdfinfo (as I guess it's in the poppler library?). Ignore me.

Comment: @Tad Dallas I tried that, returning the `Pages:    #` output to R and parsing & testing the number given, and so far it works. Thanks. I am still interested in R or other more universal answers though, since this does not work on OS X on my Mac so it will not be as portable as needed in the long-term.

Comment: Tight. You should be able to [install poppler on OS X](http://macappstore.org/poppler/), so the commands would remain the same. Any R solution will just call those libraries anyway, right? Idk.

Answer (score 14):

The other suggestions and code seem unnecessarily opaque or complicated. Once `pdftools` is installed, the `pdf_info` command will return a pages field:

```
    library(pdftools)
    # returns number of pages
    # assumes your_file_name.pdf is in working directory
    pdf_info("your_file_name.pdf")$pages  
    
    # to see other available metadata in pdf_info object, use names()
    names(pdf_info("your_file_name.pdf"))
```

Answer (score 8):

The script below worked for me.

```
#########################################
#GET PDF PAGE NUMBER :: R - JULY 16
##########################################

##SOURCE
#----pdftools package
#https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/pdftools

#Requirement
#brew install poppler
## TO AVOID ERROR ::: configure: error: cannot determine poppler-glib compile/link flags

#INSTALL PACKAGES
#install.packages("pdftools", dependencies=TRUE)  #only once

#IN/OUT FILES
in_put_pdf="pathTo/test.pdf"
out_put_pdf="pathTo/testCopy.pdf"

#LOAD LIBS
library(pdftools)

#Copy of the original file
file.copy(file.path(Sys.getenv("PATH_TO_PDF_FILE"), in_put_pdf), out_put_pdf)

#Many informations about the file are displayed here
info <- pdf_info(out_put_pdf)
text <- pdf_text(out_put_pdf)
fonts <- pdf_fonts(out_put_pdf)
files <- pdf_attachments(out_put_pdf)


#To get the number of pages
numberOfPageInPdf = info[2]
numberOfPageInPdf
```

Hope that can help. Good luck.

Comment: this looks promising but I am still having trouble getting the pdftools package installed on my primary server so it might be a while before I can test it.